# Can you move the autorun.inf file from root in a flash drive?

Tags: usb-storage

Is it possible to move the autorun.inf file in to a seperate folder in a flash drive rather than keeping it in the root?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to move autorun.inf elsewhere, but when it's not in the root, it will just be an inert data file and won't actually cause anything to happen for autorun.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't, because it's never searched from there.

> [Autorun.inf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144206(VS.85).aspx#autorun.inf) is a text file located in the root directory of the
>   CD-ROM that contains your application.

[Since Windows 7](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/srd/2009/04/28/autorun-changes-in-windows-7/) it has been optical media rather than any removable media, but that counts all devices that introduces themselves as optical drives. A normal USB flash drive doesn't act like that.

Before this change, where AutoPlay also started to prompt for the action desired, the Autorun.inf was used by default. The user had to opt-out either by pressing the shift key while inserting the media or by modifying Windows registry. Back in those old Windows XP times I considered this as such a big vulnerability I created [The Last Autorun](https://esajokinen.net/autorun/): a CD-ROM that used this feature to disable it.